# Appending .eq() resulting in duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Using this I am able to load products that contain names but when I want to append a certain name based on index I get duplicates, help much appreciated.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<catalogue>
    <product>
        <name>Cleaner</name>
        <description>Simple Desgreaser</description>
        <price>$100</price>
        <image>images/lol1.png</image>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>CSanitiser</name>
        <description>Simple Sanitiser</description>
        <price>$200</price>
        <image>images/lol1.png</image>
    </product>
</catalogue>
```

```js
function catalogueData2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "catalogueData.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('product').each(function(){
            var name = '<p>Name: '+$(xml).find("name:eq(0)").text()+'</p>';
            $("div#name").append(name);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "append a certain name based on index"? Where is the index in your code?

Comment: refer to updated post. I wish to choose the product I want appended. But so far when I do this using "eq(0)" its displaying a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(xml).find("name:eq(0)")` is the first name in the XML, not the first name in the current product in the `.each()` iteration. Use `$(this).find("name:eq(0)")` to search just the current element.

Regarding selecting a specific index, maybe something like this is what you want:

```
function catalogData2(index) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "catalogueData.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var name = '<p>Name: ' + $(xml).find("name").eq(index).text() + '</p>';
            $("div#name").append(name);
        }
    });
}
```

With this, `catalogData2(0)` will append `Cleaner`, and `catalogData2(1)` will append `Sanitizer`.

Comment: Where is the selected one determined?

Comment: It is determined in the each function and appended at the same time.

Comment: I mean, how does it know which one is selected, so only that one should be returned? Your function doesn't take an argument saying which product is selected.

Comment: I have tried both `.eq()` and `:eq()` methods of selecting from the index. `.each()` seperates each iteration into an index which I should be able to pick from, but it seems like it appends while it loops until it gets to where i want.

Comment: What index are you talking about? There's no argument to the function that says it should only select the product at a specific index. `.each()` loops over all the matching elements. You don't have an `if()` that tests the element to see if it's the selected one.

Comment: Thankyou for your help much appreciated, I managed to get this sorted before your answer, but still appreciate your help!

Comment: Is my answer close to what you wanted?

Comment: It exactly what I was after.